# How to check the statistics for all letters in alphabet

Tags: loops, t-sql

I'm checking some conditions using the `strs` table. I can do it for all the letters in the alphabet. But it will be Hard Code. Could you please tell me how to generalize the checking process?

I tried to check for each letter manually.

```
CREATE TABLE strs
(
    str_ VARCHAR(20)
);


CREATE TABLE final_data
(
    letter                VARCHAR(20),
    total                 int,
    occurance             int,
    max_occurance         int,
    max_occurance_reached int
);


INSERT INTO strs(str_)
VALUES('aa'),
      ('aaaa'),
      ('aab'),
      ('abaaba'),
      ('bbbbb');


INSERT INTO final_data(letter,total,occurance,max_occurance,max_occurance_reached)

SELECT DISTINCT tb1.letter,tb2.Total,tb3.occurance,tb4.max_occurance,tb5.max_occurance_reached FROM
(SELECT 'a' AS letter FROM  strs ) as tb1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'a' AS letter, SUM(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,'a',''))) AS Total FROM strs) AS tb2
ON tb1.letter=tb2.letter
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'a' AS letter ,COUNT(str_) AS occurance FROM strs WHERE CHARINDEX('a',str_)>0) AS tb3
ON tb2.letter=tb3.letter
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'a' AS letter, MAX(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,'a',''))) as max_occurance FROM strs) AS tb4
ON tb3.letter=tb4.letter
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'a' AS letter ,count(str_) AS max_occurance_reached FROM strs WHERE (LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,'a',''))) in (SELECT MAX(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,'a',''))) FROM strs)) AS tb5
ON tb4.letter=tb5.letter;

INSERT INTO final_data(letter,total,occurance,max_occurance,max_occurance_reached)

SELECT DISTINCT tb1.letter,tb2.Total,tb3.occurance,tb4.max_occurance,tb5.max_occurance_reached FROM
(SELECT 'b' AS letter FROM  strs ) AS tb1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'b' AS letter, sum(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,'b',''))) AS Total FROM strs) AS tb2
ON tb1.letter=tb2.letter
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'b' AS letter ,count(str_) AS occurance FROM strs WHERE CHARINDEX('b',str_)>0) AS tb3
ON tb2.letter=tb3.letter
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'b' AS letter, MAX(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,'b',''))) AS max_occurance FROM strs) AS tb4
ON tb3.letter=tb4.letter
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'b' AS letter ,count(str_) AS max_occurance_reached FROM strs WHERE (LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,'b',''))) 
in (SELECT MAX(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,'b',''))) FROM strs)) as tb5
ON tb4.letter=tb5.letter;

SELECT letter,total,occurance,max_occurance,max_occurance_reached FROM final_data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If performance is important then a set-based solution is the *only* way to go.** Using loops or similar methods will perform terribly compared to the equivalent set-based method.

My solution uses [APPLY](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-and-using-apply-part-1) and a [Tally table](http://%20https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) -- two of the most important things to learn/understand/master if you are to right high-performing SQL Queries. I know these two topics are a bit advanced so I'll break my solution into small chunks. First let's see do this for a single character.

```
DECLARE @C CHAR(1) = 'a';

SELECT
  letter        = @C,
  occurance     = SUM(IIF(f.CCount>0,1,0)),
  max_occurance = MAX(f.CCount),
  total         = SUM(f.CCount)
FROM strs
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,@C,'')))) AS f(CCount);
```

**Returns:**

```
letter occurance   max_occurance total
------ ----------- ------------- -----------
a      4           4             12
```

Next for a set-based way to create an alphabet (or any sequence of characters)

```
SELECT i.N, letter = CHAR(i.N+96)
FROM
(
  SELECT TOP (26) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM       (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS a(x)
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS b(x)
) AS i(N);
```

**Returns:**

```
N      letter
------ ------
1      a
2      b
3      c
...
25     y
26     z
```

*Side-note: you could also use [NGrams8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) to create an alphabet; this query will return the same thing...*

```
SELECT Letter = ng.token FROM dbo.NGrams8k('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',1) AS ng;
```

Now let's pass the results of our "alphabet query" to our logic for analyzing the text.

```
-- Solution that does not get max_occur_reached (full virtual index, no sort!)
SELECT 
  letter        = CHAR(i.N+96),
  total         = SUM(f.CCount),
  occurance     = SUM(IIF(f.CCount>0,1,0)),
  max_occurance = MAX(f.CCount)
FROM strs
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT TOP (26) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM       (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS a(x)
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS b(x)
) AS i(N)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,CHAR(i.N+96),'')))) AS f(CCount)
GROUP BY    i.N;
```

**Returns:**

```
letter total       occurance   max_occurance
------ ----------- ----------- -------------
a      12          4           4
b      8           3           5
c      0           0           0
....
```

Next, we add code to get our "max_occurances_reached".

```
--INSERT final_data (letter,total,occurance,max_occurance,max_occurance_reached)
SELECT
  ff.Letter, 
  total                 = SUM(ff.CCount),
  occurance             = SUM(IIF(ff.CCount>0,1,0)),
  max_occurance         = MAX(ff.max_occur),
  max_occurance_reached = SUM(ff.max_reached)
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    Letter      = CHAR(i.N+96),
    CCount      = f.CCount,
    max_occur   = MAX(f.CCount) OVER (PARTITION BY i.N),
    max_reached = IIF(f.CCount=MAX(f.CCount) OVER (PARTITION BY i.N),1,0)
  FROM strs
  CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT TOP (26) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM       (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS a(x)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS b(x)
  ) AS i(N)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,CHAR(i.N+96),'')))) AS f(CCount)
) AS ff
GROUP BY ff.Letter;
```

This will get you what you need without any loops, cursors or other low-performning techniques.

**Bonus:**

Can we do even better? If you look at the execution plan you'll see that my solution above gets a sort. Sorts are expensive but often required. Indexes pre-sort the data to avoid sorting a run time. There's sort is required to handle the `GROUP BY ff.Letter`. We can remove that sort by leveraging the ***Virtual Index***, something I talk about in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681444/how-to-generate-calendar-table-having-begin-month-date-and-end-month-date/54697612). In this case, *the virtual index exists on i.N*. This allows me to use `GROUP BY i.N`, `ORDER BY i.N`, `SELECT DISTINCT i.N`, `PARTITION BY i.N` and more without a sort in the execution plan. If I can refactor the query so that my these statements to point to i.N it will be sort-free and faster.

```
SELECT 
  Letter                = CHAR(ff.i+96), 
  total                 = SUM(ff.CCount),
  occurance             = SUM(IIF(ff.CCount>0,1,0)),
  max_occurance         = MAX(ff.max_occur),
  max_occurance_reached = SUM(ff.max_reached)
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    i           = i.N,
    CCount      = f.CCount,
    max_occur   = MAX(f.CCount) OVER (PARTITION BY i.N),
    max_reached = IIF(f.CCount=MAX(f.CCount) OVER (PARTITION BY i.N),1,0)
  FROM strs
  CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT TOP (26) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM       (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS a(x)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS b(x)
  ) AS i(N)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,CHAR(i.N+96),'')))) AS f(CCount)
) AS ff
GROUP BY ff.i;
```

Now lets compare the execution plans with and without the virtual index.

[image]

Boom! No index, no sort, no loops, woohoo!

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may try with below code

```
Declare @num tinyint, @alphabet char(1)
Declare @i int=0
While @i<26
Begin
    Select @num = 97+@i
    Select @alphabet = char(@num)

    INSERT INTO final_data(letter,total,occurance,max_occurance,max_occurance_reached)
    SELECT DISTINCT tb1.letter,tb2.Total,tb3.occurance,tb4.max_occurance,tb5.max_occurance_reached FROM
    (SELECT @alphabet AS letter FROM  strs ) as tb1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT @alphabet AS letter, SUM(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,@alphabet,''))) AS Total FROM strs) AS tb2
    ON tb1.letter=tb2.letter
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT @alphabet AS letter ,COUNT(str_) AS occurance FROM strs WHERE CHARINDEX(@alphabet,str_)>0) AS tb3
    ON tb2.letter=tb3.letter
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT @alphabet AS letter, MAX(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,@alphabet,''))) as max_occurance FROM strs) AS tb4
    ON tb3.letter=tb4.letter
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT @alphabet AS letter ,count(str_) AS max_occurance_reached FROM strs WHERE (LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,@alphabet,''))) in (SELECT MAX(LEN(str_)-LEN(REPLACE(str_,@alphabet,''))) FROM strs)) AS tb5
    ON tb4.letter=tb5.letter;

    set @i=@i+1
End

SELECT letter,total,occurance,max_occurance,max_occurance_reached FROM final_data;
```

Comment: Loops kill performance in SQL Server. Consider a set-based solution next time.