# Perform a monthly distinct beneficiary count between 1/1/2018 -12/31/2020 based on two date fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Perform a monthly distinct beneficiary count between 1/1/2018 -12/31/2020 using Microsoft SQL Server.

Below is my code but I have to change it for every month, is there any way to group by each month from 2018 to 2020 with 2 different date fields?

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct BEN_ID) 
FROM LDS_2017andbeyond
WHERE 
[DTE_FIRST_SVC] between  '2018-01-01'  and '2018-01-31'
AND 
[DTE_LAST_SVC]  between  '2018-01-01'  and '2018-01-31'
```

Comment: Start by generating a calendar containing all the months of interest. See [How to generate calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681444/how-to-generate-calendar-table-having-begin-month-date-and-end-month-date) or search for "[sql-server] calendar" for other possibilities.  From there, you can join with your data table, group by \calendar month, and calculate the count for each group.

Comment: Will DTE_FIRST_SVC and DTE_LAST_SVC always be in the same month? If not, do you want to count the record for each month that overlaps the first/last range?  If so, you might need to use an "overlapping date range" test such as `(DTE_FIRST_SVC <= MonthEnd AND DTE_LAST_SVC >= MonthStart)`.

Comment: Which date are you going to group by?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a recursive CTE.  You start with an anchor query and union it to itself with a DATEADD function in the recursive portion.  This solution will give you every month month, even if the count is 0, as opposed to just grouping on the data, which will omit any months that arn't present.

Something like:

```
WITH CTE_Date AS (
    SELECT CAST('01/01/2018' AS DATE) AS GroupMonth -- Start Date.  Set as far back as necessary.  Can use a DATEADD() to make dynamic.
    
    UNION ALL
        
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, GroupMonth) AS GroupMonth
    FROM CTE_Date
    WHERE DATEADD(month, 1, GroupMonth) < '12/31/2020' -- End Date.  Remove the where to go to current.
)
        
SELECT 
    COUNT(distinct BEN_ID),
    CAST(MONTH(d.GroupMonth) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(d.GroupMonth) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS Dt
FROM 
    LDS_2017andbeyond lds
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_Date d ON 
    MONTH(lds.[DTE_FIRST_SVC]) = MONTH(d.GroupMonth) 
    AND 
    YEAR(lds.[DTE_LAST_SVC]) = YEAR(d.GroupMonth)
GROUP BY
    CAST(MONTH(d.GroupMonth) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(d.GroupMonth) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to group dates on the same month is the [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) function.  It'll return the last day of the month for a date.

```
SELECT 
  FORMAT(EOMONTH([DTE_FIRST_SVC]), 'yyyy-MM') AS MONTH_FIRST_SVC
, FORMAT(EOMONTH([DTE_LAST_SVC]), 'yyyy-MM') AS MONTH_LAST_SVC  
, COUNT(DISTINCT BEN_ID) AS TOTAL_UNIQUE_BEN_ID
FROM LDS_2017andbeyond
WHERE [DTE_FIRST_SVC] BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
  AND [DTE_LAST_SVC]  BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY EOMONTH([DTE_FIRST_SVC]), EOMONTH([DTE_LAST_SVC])
ORDER BY MONTH_FIRST_SVC DESC, MONTH_LAST_SVC DESC
```